# Letter Series Problem (D,P,N,G....)

Tags: pattern, letter-sequence

Find the next item in this series:

D, P, N, G, C, M, M

Comment: When you would like to provide a solution to the riddle, please don't do so by posting a spoiler in the question. Instead, write an own answer where you post your solution with a spoiler tag.

Comment: You shouldn't give the solution right away, even in spoilers tags. For what I've seen here (I'm kinda new), spoilers in puzzles are usually used to provide hints, so you may spoil people with the answer while they may just be curious of the (expected) hint, or just placed their mouse in the wrong spot.

Answer (score 5):

As the intended answer was included in the question, I've copied it here as community wiki.

> The next in the series is S which stands for South Carolina. This is the pattern of states added to the union!

Comment: I can't imagine anyone figuring this out. This is a "read my mind" puzzle.

Comment: @xnor Too bad he posted the solution in the question.  Would have been interesting to see if anyone could answer it.